# Relevance to literature of 1623 ban on swearing in England

Tags: historical-context, english-renaissance-theater

In 1606, the English Parliament passed the [*Act to Restrain Abuses of Players*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Act_to_Restrain_Abuses_of_Players), and plays written after that date avoided using the names of God or Jesus "jestingly or profanely".

The Wikipedia article about [minced oaths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minced_oath) claims that

> Swearing on stage was officially banned by the Act to Restraine Abuses of Players in 1606, and a general ban on swearing followed in 1623.

However, the 1623 ban is tagged "citation needed", so the exact nature of that ban is unclear. Was it simply a ban on swearing *anywhere* or did it also mention the theatre or literature generally. The wording "general ban" suggest that it does not focus on the theatre or literature, but a citation is needed to verify that claim.
I couldn't find any other information about such a ban on [The History of Parliament Online](https://historyofparliamentonline.org/search/site/1623%20swearing?f[0]=im_field_publish_volume%3A66788) or on [British History Online](https://www.british-history.ac.uk/).

So I have a twofold question:

1. Did the English Parliament pass a ban on swearing or profane language in 1623?
2. Did this ban or act specifically mention the theatre or literature?

Comment: A more knowledgeable audience might be over at [law.se].

Comment: @muru If it's on topic here, I'd rather keep it here. I'm not impressed by the number of questions they have about [English legal history](https://law.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Blegal-history%5D+england).

Comment: Not as impressive as our own, I'm sure. I don't have a particular opinion on whether this is on topic; I was just noting that resources for looking up historical law would be somewhat different from those for looking up historical literature.

Comment: As a side note - I have seen reasonably believable assertions previously that "swearing" to 1623 people meant the original "mentioning god's name in vain" meaning, NOT "saying George Carlin's 7 bad words" meaning - the act was specifically about profanity in the original Christian religious context.

Answer (score 3):

The English Parliament did pass a ban on swearing in 1623, that much at least is agreed upon by several records:

- [*The Statutes Relating to the Ecclesiastical and Eleemosynary Institutions of England, Wales, Ireland, India, and the Colonies: With the Decisions Thereon*, Volume 1](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=GZZVAAAAYAAJ&q=Profane), Archibald John Stephens, 1845, which names the law as part of *Statuta Jacobi*:

  > XXVI. Stat. 21 Jacobi 1, c. 20(1), A.D. 1623
  >   "An act to prevent and reform profane Swearing and Cursing."
- [A BBC news article](https://www.bbc.com/news/magazine-15816761) mentions it in passing:

  > In 1601 a bill "against usual and common swering" was introduced to the House of Commons, but failed to attract enough support from MPs. However, in 1623 an act was passed against swearing, which was rigorously enforced by the Puritans.
- [A site listing "crazy English laws"](http://www.duhaime.org/LawFun/LawArticle-1339/Even-More-Crazy-English-Laws--Part-III.aspx) contains partial text of *An Act to Prevent and Reform Profane Swearing and Cursing*, passed by [King James I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobean_era) in 1623:

  > "Forasmuch as all profane swearing and cursing is forbidden by the Word of God, be it therefore enacted by the authority of this present Parliament, but no person or persons shall from henceforth profanely swear or curse. And that if any person or persons shall at any time or times hereafter offend herein.... or shall therefore be convicted by the oaths of two witnesses or by confession of the party, ... every such offender shall for every time so offending forfeit and pay to the use of the poor of that parish where the same offense is or shall be committed, the sum of 12 pence.
  >
  > "The offender, if he or she be above the age of 12 years, shall by warrant from such justice of the peace or head officer be set in the stocks by three whole hours; but if the offender be under the age of 12 years, and shall not forthwith pay the said some of 12 pence, then he or she ... shall be whipped by the Constable, or by the parents or master in his presence."
- *[An Encyclopedia of Swearing: The Social History of Oaths, Profanity, Foul Language, and Ethnic Slurs in the English-speaking World](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=sIGsBwAAQBAJ&q=1623#v=snippet&q=1623&f=false)*, Geoffrey Hughes, 2015 also contains partial text:

  > For as much as all profane swearing and cursing is forbidden by the Word of God, be it therefore enacted, by the authority of the then Parliament, but no person or persons should from henceforth profanely swear and curse, upon the Penalty of of forfeiting one Shilling to the use of the Poor for every Oath or Curse.

  This book goes on to say that the 1623 Act was "continued and ratified by the succeeding Parliament of Charles I  in 1627 (3 Chas. I. c. 4) and again, near the end of his reign in 1640."

The provisions of the 1623 Act are also apparently mentioned in the preamble of [the Profane Swearing Act of 1694](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profane_Swearing_Act_1694), so the discrepancies between the quoted text from the last two sources might because either of them used a later Act as the source instead of the 1623 Act itself. At any rate, both versions agree on the offence itself: it wasn't specifically about the theatre or literature. Hughes (2015) also lists a few other laws from that time, with quotes, so it seems to be a good resource for shoring up that Wikipedia article.

Comment: So none of these sources cite the entire text of the act, which should still be available somewhere. I'll upvote your answer, but I hope someone can find the entire text.

Comment: Some excellent forensic work!